# FPDI merge PDF files, strange line appears

Tags: php, pdf, fpdi

I have to merge PDF files when a user needs to. The files are already existing and everything is fine. I'm using the fallowing code to merge the files:

```
class concat_pdf extends FPDI 
{
    var $files = array();

    function setFiles($files) 
    {
        $this->files = $files;
    }

    function concat() 
    {
        foreach($this->files AS $file) 
        {
            $pagecount = $this->setSourceFile($file);

            for($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) 
            {
                $this->AddPage('P');
                $tplidx = $this->ImportPage($i);
                $this->useTemplate($tplidx);
            }
        }
    }
}

$pdf = new concat_pdf();
$pdf->setFiles($files); //$files is an array with existing PDF files.
$pdf->concat();
$pdf->Output("bulk.pdf", "D");
```

All files are merged and all the content is there. The problem is, at the top of each page in the new file, a black line appears. The contents, margins, etc. are all absolutely the same as the original file, but this line comes out of nowhere (that I can tell). It is not thick, but is clearly visible. It doesn't mess with the other content or anything, but is not needed there and I need to remove it.

I've tried changing the second parameter to the `ImportPage()` function to all the options described in the [documentation](http://www.setasign.de/support/manuals/fpdi/fpdi/fpdi-importpage/), but there's no difference whatsoever. Since this is the only thing that I see I can change in this few lines of code, I really don't know what is causing the black line to appear. 
I've searched for similar issues, but so far - no luck. Anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance!

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: Would you add a screenshot? - would probably be the best way of illustrating the issue.

Comment: I added screenshots, but since I cannot reveal the contents of the files, I've only cut what is seen at the top when opening the same file - once normal, once merged with other files. Everything below is absolutely identically positioned.

Answer (score 27):

A better thing to do as you won't have to modify the source is to add the lines:

```
    $this->setPrintHeader(false);
    $this->setPrintFooter(false);
```

at the beginning of your concat() function.

Comment: Thank you, simple but effective. :)

Answer (score 5):

To avoid editing the TCPDF library, overwrite the methods Footer and Header in your extended class.

```
class concat_pdf extends FPDI 
{
    public function Footer() {}
    public function Header() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solution of this issue. Default header and footer in tcpdf contains line. You have to erase body of methods footer() and header() in tcpdf class on line 4214.

Comment: You should not edit the tcpdf class itself as it can be easily overwritten if you update the lib.